# Border + Heading + Navigation - positioning issues

Tags: html, css, positioning

I would like to have a heading (on the left side) and a vertical navigation (on the right side) on the same height and about 10-20px below a border indicating a line below these two elements.

I tried realising it for over an hour now, however, without success.

My current source code: http://jsfiddle.net/j72p9/

```
<header>
    <h1>Headline on the left</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">On The</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="clearfix"></div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
}

#clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

/* Nav. Style */

header nav > ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: what are you trying to do? more detail please

Comment: @IPADDRESS: As you can see in the fiddle, the navigation and the text on the left are not on the same level/height. The navigation is positioned higher than the h1-element.

Answer (score 0):

heres your answer http://jsfiddle.net/j72p9/1/

html:

```
   <div style="display: table; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;background:yellow;">
   <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
   <div>
     everything is vertically centered in modern IE8+ and others.
   </div>
   </div>
   <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
   <div>
     everything is vertically centered in modern IE8+ and others.
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: No, that's not doing what it's supposed to do. It's not floating the two parts to the right and left.

Comment: just change the css styling and add widths

Comment: The width of the navigation could change from time to time - I don't always want to have to adjust widths in a css file.

Comment: the code i uploaded is responsive. i will upload a different solution then

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is the following one: (take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/j72p9/)

```
header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0
}

header nav {
    float: right;
}

#clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

header nav {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* Nav. Style */
header nav > ul {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 0;
}

header nav > ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Then you need to use a little of jQuery:

```
jQuery('header nav').css('line-height', jQuery('header h1').height() + 'px')
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: table` and 100% width is a good option if I understand your requirement.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/j72p9/4/)

HTML

```
<header>
    <h1>
        Headline on the left
    </h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Navigation</a> <a href="#">On The</a> <a href="#">Right</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
header h1 {
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav a {
    margin: 0 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```